# Check whether typed password is matched

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I wanted to create a function where user key in a password and it has to match with this password (`pwd1209!`). When user click on `submit button`, it will check whether the typed password is matched with `pwd1209!`.

```
      <input type="password" id="pwd" class="form" placeholder="type your 
       password">

      <button class="btn" id="submit"> Submit</button>



      $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#submit").click(function (e) {
            if ($('#pwd').val() == '') {
                alert('Key in a password.');
            }
        if ($('#pwd').val() != pwd1209!){
                alert('Incorrect password.');
        }
        else{
            alert('Correct password.');
        }



      });
```

Comment: well what is `pwd1209!`? It is not a string. I am sure your developer console has a nice error message.

Comment: just a password @epascarello

Comment: You missed my point. You correctly defined strings in other places in your code.

Comment: And I assume you have errors in the above code with copy and pasting of the closing brackets.

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you post a question, they belong to the site and its users. Even if it is no longer useful to you, it might be helpful to someone in the future. The answerers would have also put an effort in writing their answer, which would no longer be useful if you have removed the content from the post. Also, note that by posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

Your JS code is incomplete, apart of this, the key to your problem was that the password is a string, therefore it must be within quotes. For sure your solution is quite insecure as JS is visible so anyone can discover the password, you should try a backend solution to do the password check.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    if ($('#pwd').val() === '') {
      alert('Add the password.');
    } else if ($('#pwd').val() !== 'pwd1209!') {
      alert('Incorrect password.');
    } else {
      alert('Correct password');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" id="pwd" class="form" placeholder="type your password">
<button class="btn" id="submit"> Submit</button>
```

Comment: how to do a backend solution for the password?